# Intellij idea angular cli in menu not showing

Tags: angular, intellij-idea, angular-cli

On one of my intellij IDEA projects I can go to File > new > angular cli. However, on another project where I imported maven projects before the angular project, I can't get the angular cli menu option. Any ideas what I need to do?

Comment: You could try making a new module, and then selecting static web. It should be there.

Answer (score 1):

To enable **angular-cli** actions in **New** menu, you normally need to ensure that there is `.angular-cli.json` in your project root folder. This won't work if this file is located in a subfolder (see [WEB-24662](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-24662), it is fixed in 2017.2)

Comment: I added .angular-cli to the parent project (first module I opened) and the context menu now appears. However, there are no options in the context menu (class, component, directive, etc). Any ideas what else I can do?

Comment: what cli version do you use?

Comment: CLI version 1.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Angular 6, `angular-cli.json` file is replaced with `angular.json` file. Yet older versions of IntelliJ IDEA keeps looking for `angular-cli.json` file in order to provide framwork support. So simply upgrading IntelliJ IDEA to a newer version should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It appeared for me after installing the angular**JS** plugin, as per instructions [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/using-angular.html#d461255e133).